# rounding off a 2 decimal places

Tags: vb.net

```
FormatNumber(totalvat, 2)
```

above is my code to round off the double. but instead of 223.66 result. it gives me 223.67 result.

in calculator the result is 223.6607142857143

can someone help me with this ? thanks!

Comment: Don't use `FormatNumber` in VB.NET.  Call the `ToString` method of the number itself and pass the appropriate format specifier, e.g. "n2" or "f2". That said, you may end up with the same result because I would have expected `FormatNumber` to round in a conventional way rather than always up. Maybe show us the code and data that produced the value of `totalvat` in the first place. Maybe your expectations are off.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
 dim s as decimal = 223.6607142857143
 console.WriteLine(s.ToString("###.##"))
```